# How do I find all possible ways to combine items in a list without repetition?

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have six categories: A, B, C, D, E, and F.

I want to find out all the unique ways I can combine the categories, without repetition.

For example, if I combine the first three categories, I will get A, A, A, B, C, D. If I combine B, C, D, E, I will get A, B, B, B, B, C.

I tried itertools. itertools.product comes close, but there is a lot of repetition. For example, I get A, B, A, A, C, D, but I also get B, A, B, B, D, C, which is a duplicate in my case. The order matters, replacement matters, the count matter, but the character does not matter.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do multiple permutations of possibilities based on number of unique characters. So permutations of 2 unique characters represented as the number of times the unique character would appear: (1,5)=(A, B, B, B, B, B)... (2,4) (3,3). 3 unique (1,1,4) (1,2,3)(2,2,2). 4 unique (1,1,1,3) (1,1,2,2). 5 unique (1,1,1,1,2). 6 unique (1,1,1,1,1,1). There is a finite amount of combinations here. Then use itertools permutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have 6 categories you can use itertools.product and then filter your result according to your criteria.

Your examples are somewhat confusing as I'm not sure how you get 'AAABCD' from  the first three categories 'ABC' which doesn't contain 'D', or how you get 'ABBBBC' by combining 'BCDEI' which doesn't contain 'A'. However assuming you want to get all the unique combinations of some subset of 'ABCDEF', of length 6, up to symbol replacement you can do this.

```
from itertools import product

CATEGORIES = 'ABCDEF'

def combinations(cats):
    # use itertools to get all combinations 
    all_combs = product(cats,repeat=len(CATEGORIES))
    valid_combs = set()

    # For every possible combination find the order in which the characters appear
    for s in all_combs:
        s = ''.join(s)
        order = []
        for c in s:
            if c not in order: 
                order.append(c)

        # replace the character by ones following a set predetermined order
        for i,c in enumerate(order):
            replace_char = CATEGORIES[i].lower()
            s = s.replace(c, replace_char)

        # add to set to remove duplicates
        s = s.upper()
        valid_combs.add(s)
    return list(valid_combs)
```

usage

```
combinations('AB') 
['ABABBB', 'ABABBA', 'AABBBB', 'ABAABB', 'ABBAAA', 'AABAAA', 'AABABB', 'AAABAB', 'AABABA', 'AABAAB', 'ABAAAB', 'AABBAB', 'AAAAAB', 'ABBAAB', 'ABBABA', 'ABBABB', 'AAAABA', 'ABAAAA', 'AAABAA', 'ABAABA', 'ABBBAB', 'AAABBB', 'ABBBBA', 'AAABBA', 'AABBAA', 'ABABAA', 'AAAAAA', 'ABBBBB', 'ABABAB', 'ABBBAA', 'AABBBA', 'AAAABB']
```

The rationale of this is that if 'ABAACD' and 'BABBDC' belong to the same equivalence class, then the member where the characters appear in order is a unique representative of that equivalence class.

This isn't very efficient though, so for a much larger list of categories you may need to construct the list directly.

Comment: Are you aware of a label that describes this set (e.g. similar to product, combinations, permutations)?

Comment: @rabouillet I was thinking about whether this set has a name, but I don't know unfortunately. This problem is somewhat similar to [the partition of a positive integer n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) problem. However it's not quite the same because for each possible partition there are multiple ways of choosing categories that satisfy it ie. for 1+1+1+1+2=6 you can have 'ABCDEE' or 'ABCDFF'. The best way I think you can describe the set is the n-fold Cartesian product partitioned by the equivalence relation x~y if the symbols can be replaced such that x=y.